# Using webform 4.x values in other fields/descriptions on multi-page webforms

Tags: webforms, tokens

Is there a way to output values of other field values in a multi-page webform? Say I have a 3 page webform. First page is name, email, then address. How can I reference the name value in the last page of my webform? I tried [webform:val-name] and it doesnt work in the description field.

Or is there a way I can call it via javascript? Are these values stored somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Once you complete an specific field in one page, it can be used ONLY in the next page.
The variables are stored into ->

```
$form_state['input']['submitted']['your_field_machine_name']
```

One trick I did, I saved that submitted variable into a hidden input in the next page.